# Weird behavior with a RelativeLayout and the Galaxy S4

Tags: android, android-layout, galaxy

This is not the first time that such a thing occured with my galaxy S4.
Here is the situation :

I have a layout in which I want to center in parent a thin line and center horizontally above and below two other views.
I managed to achieve the desired effect on every android phone I could get my hands on except the galaxy S4.

Tested phones :

- **Nexus 6** (Android 5.1.1) - WORKING
- **Nexus 4** (Android 5.1.1) - WORKING
- **Wiko Darkfull** (Android 4.2.1) - WORKING
- **Galaxy S4 GT-I9505** (Android 4.4.2) - NOT WORKING

Here is the effect that is working on every phone except the S4 :

[image: Working]

And here is the effect I have on the S4 :

[image: Not Working]

The relevant part of the code is :

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black_blur_12">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_group_white_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/separator"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="0"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

As I said, it is not the first time I have a problem with layouts and the galaxy S4. 
All the ROMS are official.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I dont know whats up with the galaxy s4. But I'll say you should use `LinearLayout` with orientation being vertical instead of `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks @Max ! However it is rather difficult to achieve this effect with a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: No not really. set `layout_gravity="center"` and  also gravity of `TextView` to `center`.

Comment: @Max Thanks for the tip, I managed to achieve the same effect I wanted with a `LinearLayout` and setting `android:gravity="center"`. However it still does not explain the S4's strange behavior!